# Testing interaction terms individually and simultaneously

Tags: regression, p-value, least-squares, interaction

I am currently testing two interaction terms individually in OLS regressions. Both interaction terms are significant (p < .5) when tested individually (i.e., two regression equations, one for each interaction term) but both interaction terms become insignificant (p > .1) when tested at the same time (i.e., two interaction terms in a single regression equation). The correlation between my two moderators is moderate ($r = 0.44$). What might be some possible reasons for the terms becoming insignificant when tested simultaneously?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by simultaneous testing? What are the p-values in each case?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you are "testing at the same time"?  Are you consulting the individual p-values or are you perhaps examining the F statistic for the two interactions together?

Comment: Re the edit: this is an example of a phenomenon discussed in many good posts.  See the hits at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20significant%20insignificant%20score%3a5.

Comment: Sorry if it is still confusing. When I test both interaction terms in a single regression equation both interaction terms become insignificant (p > .1).

Comment: @user18075 I think it's more clear now, but what is more clear is that you should read the link from whuber, this has been discussed over and over before.